# how to change view, update and delete url on action column in yii2

Tags: yii2

I have create action on update and view in controller, but this action does not change on action column in index page

```
 public function actionLeadView($id){
   $id =  $_GET['id'];
   $model = Leads::findOne($id);
   return $this->render('viewlead', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
 }    
 public function actionLeadUpdate($id){
   $id =  $_GET['id'];
   $model = Leads::findOne($id);
   date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
   $date = date('Y/m/d H-i-sa');       
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
      $model->modified = $date;
      if($model->validate()){
         $model->save();
         return $this->redirect(['viewlead', 'id' => $model->id]);                
            }else {
            return $this->render('updatelead', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
      }    
   } 
   else 
   {
        return $this->render('updatelead', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
       [
          'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
          'header' => 'Actions',
          'headerOptions' => ['style' => 'color:#337ab7'],
          'template' => '{view}{update}{delete}',
          'buttons' => [
            'view' => function ($url, $model) {
                return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>', $url, [
                            'title' => Yii::t('app', 'lead-view'),
                ]);
            },

            'update' => function ($url, $model) {
                return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>', $url, [
                            'title' => Yii::t('app', 'lead-update'),
                ]);
            },
            'delete' => function ($url, $model) {
                return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>', $url, [
                            'title' => Yii::t('app', 'lead-delete'),
                ]);
            }

          ],
          'urlCreator' => function ($action, $model, $key, $index) {
            if ($action === 'view') {
                $url ='index.php?r=client-login/lead-view&id='.$model->id;
                return $url;
            }

            if ($action === 'update') {
                $url ='index.php?r=client-login/lead-update&id='.$model->id;
                return $url;
            }
            if ($action === 'delete') {
                $url ='index.php?r=client-login/lead-delete&id='.$model->id;
                return $url;
            }

          }
          ],
```

Comment: Nice Answer! Well Done.

Comment: For extra flexibility, you could use [Url helper class](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html), like so `return \yii\helpers\Url::to(['/controller/action', 'param1' => 'param1value', 'param2' => 'param2value']); `. That way in the case that you rename your Controller Actions, the routing scheme will only need minimal adjustments, and all your links everywhere will adjust accordingly automatically.

Answer (score 17):

Often you need to change just controller name in action button's url. You can do it simple using **urlCreator**

```
[
    'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
    'urlCreator' => function ($action, $model, $key, $index) {
        return Url::to(['another-controller-name/'.$action, 'id' => $model->id]);
    }
],
```

Answer (score 8):

In gridview,

```
[
    'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
    'template' => '{leadView} {leadUpdate}',
    'buttons' => [
       'leadView' => function ($url, $model) {
           $url = Url::to(['controller/lead-view', 'id' => $model->whatever_id]);
          return Html::a('<span class="fa fa-eye"></span>', $url, ['title' => 'view']);
       },
       'leadUpdate' => function ($url, $model) {
           $url = Url::to(['controller/lead-update', 'id' => $model->whatever_id]);
           return Html::a('<span class="fa fa-pencil"></span>', $url, ['title' => 'update']);
       },
    ]
]
```

Comment: Please update the answer. One closing squere bracket is missing  'buttons' => [ --

Answer (score 7):

Since the question is

> how to change view, update and **delete** url on action column in yii2

I'm improving the answer of @insane-skull by adding delete action

```
[
'class'    => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
'template' => '{leadView} {leadUpdate} {leadDelete}',
'buttons'  => [
    'leadView'   => function ($url, $model) {
        $url = Url::to(['controller/lead-view', 'id' => $model->whatever_id]);
        return Html::a('<span class="fa fa-eye"></span>', $url, ['title' => 'view']);
    },
    'leadUpdate' => function ($url, $model) {
        $url = Url::to(['controller/lead-update', 'id' => $model->whatever_id]);
        return Html::a('<span class="fa fa-pencil"></span>', $url, ['title' => 'update']);
    },
    'leadDelete' => function ($url, $model) {
        $url = Url::to(['controller/lead-delete', 'id' => $model->whatever_id]);
        return Html::a('<span class="fa fa-trash"></span>', $url, [
            'title'        => 'delete',
            'data-confirm' => Yii::t('yii', 'Are you sure you want to delete this item?'),
            'data-method'  => 'post',
        ]);
    },
]
```

]

Answer (score 1):

I am new in `Yii2`, thank you for helping me with your code @cbaconnier.
This is your code, with a little modification:

```
[
'class'    => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
'template' => '{leadView} {leadUpdate} {leadDelete}',
'buttons'  => [
    'leadView'   => function ($url, $model) {
        $url = Url::to(['datakegiatan/view', 'id' => $model->ID_DATA]);
        return Html::a('<span class="fa fa-eye"></span>', $url, ['title' => 'view']);
    },
    'leadUpdate' => function ($url, $model) {
        $url = Url::to(['datakegiatan/update', 'id' => $model->ID_DATA]);
        return Html::a('<span class="fa fa-pencil"></span>', $url, ['title' => 'update']);
    },
    'leadDelete' => function ($url, $model) {
        $url = Url::to(['datakegiatan/delete', 'id' => $model->ID_DATA]);
        return Html::a('<span class="fa fa-trash"></span>', $url, [
            'title'        => 'delete',
            'data-confirm' => Yii::t('yii', 'Are you sure you want to delete this item?'),
            'data-method'  => 'post',
        ]);
    },
]],
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to change the urls and keep the default buttons, use the attribute `urlCreator`.

```
'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
        'template' => '{delete} ',
        'urlCreator' => function ($action, $model, $key, $index) {
            return Url:to(["controller/action"]);
        }
```